# Как присоединить сюда admin_id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def spam_photo(message: types.Message):
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    users = db.get_subscriptions()
    for i in users:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=int(i[0]), photo=file_id)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await message.answer("ОТправка завершена")
```

Comment: куда сюда? О чём вообще вопрос?

Comment: боту скидывают фото он делает рассылку. Надо чтобы ток Админ мог т.е я

Comment: А id админа знаешь?)